# How to get the scope created by inner directive from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <div id="aaa" myd1>
      In a directive
    </div>
    <button ng-click="showDirectiveScope()">Show Directive Scope</button>
</body>
```

Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$element) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.showDirectiveScope = function() {
        var aaa = $element.find("#aaa");
        console.log(aaa);
        console.log(angular.element(aaa).scope());
    }
});

app.directive('myd1', function(){
    return {
        scope: true
    }
});
```

There will be a **Show Directive Scope** button in the page. When I click it, I want angular to find the DOM with `id=aaa`, then get and log it's scope created by directive `myd1`.

But it will print `undefined`, where is wrong?

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ravJoVH2oGLDD0VUsO82?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) doesn't support selectors.  Include jQuery before Angular in your plunker and it will work:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

You can also simplify your log a bit, since var `aaa` is a wrapped jQuery element:

```
console.log(aaa.scope());
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bUsxo2UBWuiNkXBf8fsI?p=preview

Comment: `$element.find("#aaa")` can find the correct DOM, see the log: `[ready: function, toString: function, eq: function, push: function, sort: function…]`

Comment: @Freewind, that's the wrong element.  When you add jQuery, the log then shows `[div#aaa.ng-scope, prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: body.ng-scope, selector: "#aaa", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]`.  Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bUsxo2UBWuiNkXBf8fsI?p=preview

Comment: You are right! And I also wonder there is any solution without using jQuery?

Answer (score 5):

Answer without jQuery:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$element,$window) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.showDirectiveScope = function() {
        var aaa = $window.document.getElementById('aaa');
        console.log(aaa);
        console.log(angular.element(aaa).scope());
        console.log($element.scope());
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes! We can use `getElementById`!

Comment: is this the best way to get hold of a angular-ui-map maps object in a inner directive?